# breaks while loop when all die rolls the same number

Tags: c#, random, die

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace AnyDice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int diceSides;
            int rollDie;
            int count = 0;
            bool keepRolling = true;
            List<int> num = new List<int>();
            Random random = new Random();

            Console.Write("Write the number of sides of your die: ");
            diceSides = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Type the numbers of the die");

            for (int i = 0; i < diceSides; i++)
            {
                int rank = 1 + i;
                Console.Write(rank + "~~> ");
                num.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            }

            num.Sort();

            Console.WriteLine("\nHere's the die and its contents");
            for (int i = 0; i < num.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("[");
                Console.Write(num[i]);
                Console.Write("]");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nHow many times do you want to roll at once");
            rollDie = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (keepRolling)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rollDie; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("[");
                    Console.Write(num[random.Next(num.Count)]);
                    Console.Write("]");
                    count++;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("It took you " + count + " attempts");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

For example if (4,4,4,4) is rolled or (2,2) in any "n" number of column the while loop breaks.
I thought of storing each die rolled value in another arraylist and comparing each value in it. If its all equal then it breaks.. but I have no clue on how to implement it.

Comment: if (num.Distinct().Count() == 1) { }

Comment: I edited your code example so there is one statement per line. It is extremely rare in C# to put multiple statements on the same line and I think it would have confused anyone trying to answer your question.

Comment: basically break while loop when all the rolled die is the same exact number

Comment: @jdweng `num` is the die, not the rolls.

Comment: Add a `List<int>` to track the rolls: `var rolls = new List<int>();`. Store each roll in the list: `var roll = num[random.Next(num.Count)]; rolls.Add(roll);` and `Console.Write(roll);` Then test if the rolls are the same: `keepRolling = rolls.Distinct().Count() == 1;`

Comment: @NetMage : Num is the roll for each of the die.  There is no need for two separate variables.

Comment: @jdweng No - look at the code and print outs. The die is allowed to have any numbers on the faces, and num is the numbers on the faces of the die. Then the (single) die is rolled multiple times in the last loop.

Comment: @NetMage : So what???  The array num has the value for each roll.  So if distinct has one item than all the rolls have the same value.  Looks like you copied my solution.

Comment: @jdweng Incorrect. They array `num` has the face values for a single die. The faces (numbers) that are rolled (`rollDie` times) are not stored in the original code.

Comment: The face values are a constant number 1 to 6 and you do not need a variable for a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have Linq. It lives in the `System.Linq` namespace and this might help you.

I'll should two ways of checking if all die are the same:

```cs
int first = dies.First();
if (dies.All(i => i == first))
{
  // break if all are equals to the first die
}
```

Or using `Distinct` we can filter out any copies.

```cs
if (dies.Distinct().Count() == 1)
{
  // if we only have unique items and the count is 1 every die is the same
}
```

Comment: This is a horrible solution.  You are using two variables when you can just use one variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your requirement, but in any case, you should write a separate function that returns a flag indicating whether the array is in a state that should trigger a break.

```
bool KeepRolling(int[] num)
{
    for (int i=0; i<num.Length; i++)
    {
        if (num[i] >= i) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then just call it from within your loop:

```
keepRolling = KeepRolling(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            while (keepRolling)
            {
                rolls.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < rollDie; i++)
                {
                    var firstRoll = num[random.Next(num.Count)];
                    rolls.Add(firstRoll);
                    Console.Write(firstRoll + " ");
                    count++;
                }
                if (rolls.Distinct().Count() == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It took you " + count + " attempts");
                    keepRolling = false;
                    break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.